# Cursor: invalid statement in "fillWindow();"

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting this error:

> Cursor: invalid statement in fillWindow()

What does it mean? Any suggestions on how to overcome it?

Comment: Is it problem with cursor or DB ???? any alternate way to close both at the end of programming???

Comment: What is the code that throws this error, post the relavent logcat also.

Comment: @AdilSoomro -- its throws error Cursor: invalid statement in fillWindow(). no more error with this only single line error.

Comment: yup @AdilSoomro its single line error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now i have solved this problem. DB n cursor was not closed properly. when i was pressing back button its was getting crashed. so i used this code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_EDIT )
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

by this activity we can close all DB.

Thanks to all for giving suggestions. 
enjoy take care :)

Comment: I'm getting error on ACTIVITY_EDIT.. Whats ACTIVITY_EDIT??